# wants to trace the data after ETL through the pipeline in snowflake so, how to automate it using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

in our project after performing the ETL in ssms data will be moved to snowflake dwh and followed with streams in snowflake till the last table/view.
so, now i want to automate this process from ssms to snowflake last table to trace the data using python
how to do it?

Not yet tried i dont know how to do

Comment: A better description of the problem would be good, I am not sure I get completely what you mean by last table.